# Jumping slows x-velocity: Jump and Run with Libgdx/Box2D

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm currently working on a platformer with libgdx and box2d(Java).
After I implemented the jump I found out that whenever I jump it slows the x-velocity of my player(a dynamic body).
Im relative new to box2d and would be happy if someone can help me :)
So because I wanted the player to move right permanently, I decided to give the world an x and an y gravity:

```
world = new World(new Vector2(100f,-200f),true);
```

Then I check if the player presses the Up Key to jump:

```
 if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.UP) && (onPlatform == true ||
 onGround == true)){
 yvelocity = 250;}
```

After that I add the velocity to the players body:

```
 body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0f, 
 yvelocity),body.getWorldCenter(),true);
```

Sincerely Lukas :)

Comment: "because I wanted the player to move right permanently, I decided to give the world an x and an y gravity".  This new gravity will affect *all* bodies, not just the player.